# How to grab webbrowser.document using caliburn.micro WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, caliburn.micro

I have a web browser in WPF

```
<WebBrowser x:Name="WebBrowserControl" Width="1000" Height="600" Source="https://www.1.com" cal:Message.Attach="[Event LoadCompleted]=[Action LoadCompleted($eventArgs)]"/>
```

It loads the www.1.com and when i click a button on 1.com it jump to http://2.com
I listen to loadCompleted event

```
public void LoadCompleted(NavigationEventArgs e)
{          
    if (e.Uri.AbsoluteUri == "https://www.2.com")
    {
         //Here i want to get WebBrowserControl.Document as mshtml.HTMLDocument;
        MessageBox.Show("Completed loading the page");
    }
}
```

I want to get 2.com htmlDocument. is there a way to achieve that. I achieve that in not viewmodel way.

```
private void WebBrowserControl_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    string[] tags = new string[]{};

    if (e.Uri.OriginalString == "https://www.2.com")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("here");
        var document = WebBrowserControl.Document as mshtml.HTMLDocument;                                                           
    }
}
```

I did something like this

```
//view
cal:Message.Attach="[Event LoadCompleted]=[Action LoadCompleted(WebBrowserControl.Document,$eventArgs)]"

//ViewModel
public void LoadCompleted(mshtml.HTMLDocument x ,NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    //it calls this method but the x is null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<WebBrowser x:Name="WebBrowserControl" Width="1000" Height="600"  Source="https://www.1.com" cal:Message.Attach="[Event LoadCompleted]=[Action LoadCompleted($source,$eventArgs)]"/>


public void LoadCompleted(object sender ,NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    WebBrowser x = (WebBrowser)sender;
    var document = x.Document as mshtml.HTMLDocument;
}
```